# How we can show $\mathbb{E}[T]=0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(T)=\frac{n}{n-2}$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-explanation

I need help with this question.

> Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim X^2_{(n)}$ be independent variables, and define$$T\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\frac{Z}{\sqrt{\frac{Y}{n}}}.$$
>   Prove that $\mathbb{E}[T]=0$and $\operatorname{Var}(T)=\frac{n}{n-2}$.

I am not sure how to do this.

**Edit**: 
I only know that $\mathbb{E}[Z]=0$, $\operatorname{Var}(Z)=1$, $\mathbb{E}[Y]=n$, and $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=2n$.

thanks

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question to show what you tried, and change the wording. *We* don't "have to proof (sic)" anything...

Comment: Hi, sorry, but i dont even know where to start.

Comment: See my answer, then. (It only provides an outline to get you started, not a full-fledged answer.)

Comment: @neto333 What is the "d" in the definition of $T$?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I hadn't seen that one. A typo, I assume?

Comment: sorry, was a finger mistake, im still learning how write properly here. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.**

- By independence of $Z$ and $Y$, we have
  $$
  \mathbb{E}[f(Z)g(Y)] = \mathbb{E}[f(Z)]\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]
  $$
  for any measurable functions $f,g$. Can you use that to show that $\mathbb{E}[T]=0$, knowing that $\mathbb{E}[Z]=0$?
- From there, $\operatorname{Var} T = \mathbb{E}[T^2] - \mathbb{E}[T]^2 = \mathbb{E}[T^2] = n\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{Z^2}{Y}\right]$. Using the same independence property, and the expectations $\mathbb{E}[Z^2]$ (it's $1$ since $Z\sim\mathcal{G}(0,1)$) and [$\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{Y}]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-chi-squared_distribution), you should be able to conclude.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats all i need :D.